# Graph Request Error 500

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My app uses Facebook Login Button of facebook-android-sdk.
It was working until last days, now on a graph request on a page's feed

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,icon,created_time,name,caption,description,message,link,full_picture,shares");
parameters.putString("limit", "50");
parameters.putString("locale", mLocale);
String pathPosts = path + "/posts";
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), pathPosts, parameters, HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                GraphResponse response) {
                mResponse = response;
                }
        });
request.executeAndWait();
```

I get the OAuthException error

> {Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An unknown error has occurred.}}

**UPDATE** 
Found that with limit lower-equal than 33 it works without errors

```
parameters.putString("limit", "33");
```

For another page's feed the limit must be lower-equal than 7 to work  without errors

```
parameters.putString("limit", "7");
```

**Question:
what is now the rule for the limit in a graph api request for page's feed?**

Comment: check if you have any wrong constructor, or  forgot to include permissions.  also there is quite possibility that the login status or access token has expired, been revoked, or is otherwise invalid. Get a new access token.

Comment: What version of the GraphAPI are you using?

Comment: @PN10 Token is valid and works on both app and Graph Api Explorer. My issue is that I get errors when the limit is greater variable values.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes On app facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0, on Grpah Api Explorer Api v2.8

Comment: Did you try to debug using debug=all parameter ? What does the response JSON return ?

Comment: @AsutoshPanda Now I get no more errors on app and on Graph Api Explorer, it seems that the issue solved by itself.  I will try when this strange behavior of the Api will happen in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Graph API has also got a Debug Mode. You need to pass an extra parameter **debug=all** in the REST API. It will give you the reason for the issue too in the response JSON if there is any issue.

Quoting Facebook documentation -

> When Debug Mode is enabled, Graph API response may contain additional
>   fields that explain potential issues with the request. To enable debug
>   mode, use the debug query string parameter. For example:
>
> GET graph.facebook.com   /v2.3/me/friends
>       access_token=...&
>       debug=all

In your code, try changing this

```
String pathPosts = path + "/posts";
```

to this

```
String pathPosts = path + "/posts&debug=all";
```

Or

Add and an extra parameter "debug" "all" in your Bundle

**and check what debug message you got**

For more info on handling errors and debugging Graph API, see here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors